# Update the query limit of elasticsearch using java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am trying to update the limit for number of results returned from elasticsearch in my java spring boot application

```
index.max_result_window: 15000
```

I have tried by doing

```
UpdateSettingsRequest updateSettingsRequest = new UpdateSettingsRequest("index");
updateSettingsRequest.settings(Settings.builder()
        .put("index.max_result_window", 15000)
);
elsRestClient.indices().putSettings(updateSettingsRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

But it does not work and the total results returned are still 10000. I haven't found the solution for this.

Comment: Can you please put the code sinppet which you are using to query to elasticsearch ?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to not change the `index.max_result_window` as it have impact on performance. You can read more about this [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html).

You can use [Search After](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after) functionality of elasticsearch to retrive more data from elastic. You can see java example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141155/how-to-use-search-after-in-elastic-high-level-rest-client-for-pagination).

You can enabled track total hits in your query request so it will return number of total result found. You can check [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-your-data.html#track-total-hits) documentation.

Comment: How can I make elasticsearch to return the actual totalHits value. I have synced more than 10000 items to elastic search. But the totalHits just 10000

Comment: Elasticsearch limit 10k result by default. You can enabled `track_total_hits` with value `true` so it will return actual count when more then 10k documents are matching. For retriving more then 10k document you need to use search after or scroll API as changing `index.max_result_window` will impact performance. I hope this will help you to understand more clearly.